# Creating this Pitch bend noise

Tags: sound-design, synthesis, replication

Hey guys Im trying to create this pitch bending synth sort of noise that I hear alot.  I got pretty close to emulating this sound.  You can here it in the following track at 2:51.  It sounds like a pitch bend sort of noise:

What Im doing so far is using two square waves that have a pitch bend on each oscillator with an envelope with a short attack  medium decay and no sustain or release.  Im also using an short envelope on the low pass filter with no attack medium decay and halfway sustain, no release.  Resonance at 10:30 or so.  Below is my configuration in massive.

[image]

I got kind of close to creating it but doing more of an educational sort of post to kind of see how the rest of the community would make this noise.  It would be cool if alot of us can get involved

UPDATE:  The sound I made sounds like the following: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz7u6sri5SdsWHd3R1FSVm81UjA

I think maybe the envelope creating the pitch bend is a bit more of an exponential slop but dunno how to do that in massive

Comment: Do you mean the little brass fill? Sounds more like just legato changing of notes than a real pitch bend to me.

Comment: you here it again at 4:41,  it occurs after the brass fill, .  I got pretty close it just sounds like this : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bz7u6sri5SdsWHd3R1FSVm81UjA  there is a more exponential slope on the decay of the envolope creating the pitch bend.